# HTML Parsing: Get content from inner tags

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

**Test input file:**

```
# cat test.html 
<div>line 1<div>Another 1</div></div>
<div>line 2<div>Another 2</div></div>
<div>line 3<div>Another 3</div></div>
```

**Expected output:**

```
Another 1
Another 2
Another 3
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;

# $tree->ignore_ignorable_whitespace(0);
# $tree->no_space_compacting(1)

$tree->parse_file("test.html");

foreach my $a ($tree->find("div")) 
{
  print $a->as_text."\n";
}
```

**Script Output:**

```
line 1Another 1
Another 1
line 2Another 2
Another 2
line 3Another 3
Another 3
```

**QUESTION:**
I am seeking help in extracting only the content from ***inner*** `div` tags. My script outputs the `line 1Another 1` first and then it outputs `Another 1`. However, I am interested only in `Another 1`.

I tried playing around with [ignore_ignorable_whitespace](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm#ignore_ignorable_whitespace) and [no_space_compacting](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm#no_space_compacting) (as seen in the script comments) but it did not work. Either I am not using it correctly OR I am barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1):

You are finding all the `div` elements when you want just the inner ones. The `findnodes` method takes an XPath expression, so you can write

```
print $_->as_text, "\n" for $tree->findnodes('div/div')
```